# Preventing the uninstall of an app - samsung tab

Tags: samsung

I know that in android 5.0 there was a package system file named "package installer" , I used to delete it so I could prevent users from uninstalling any application.
WHO knows what is the file name of the same file for android 6 - 7 for the samsung tablets?

Same question for the settings.apk for android 5 - what did it become for android 6 & 7??

Answer (score 0):

Now it's called "GooglePackageInstaller" and it's located in root/system/priv-app/GooglePackageInstaller/

Settings app is called "SecSettings2" and it's located in root/system/priv-app/SecSettings2/

The screenshots are from an S7 running 7.0, should be the same for the tablets as well.

[image: Location]
[image: Just to confirm]

Comment: Thank you, yes & the package is com.googlepackageinstaller but the problem is that in lollipop you can simply delete it & the system continues working, while on android 7, the system fails. Any more tip?

Comment: I'm sorry, haven't tried removing it..so can't say.